# Show/hide item in "_layout"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a C# MVC project and I want a master page that has a header that contains some information among which is the application logo on the top left corner. However, there's one view in which I don't want it to be seen, the login page.

So, how can I hide it for just the `Home/Index` view and then display it for all the other views?

Here's part of the `_Layout.cshtml`

```
...
   <body>
        <header>

            <div class="content-wrapper">

                <div class="float-left">
                    <a href="../Home/Index"><img src="../../Images/_logo.png" alt="whatever" /></a>
                </div>
...
```

This shows in every page, I just wish I could hide it from the initial page where the user enters its credentials.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set Layout = null for that Login page.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is what I'm looking for but as it removed styles from the login page I'm going to work on it to see if it fits me

Comment: You have to manually attached your CSS to login page as it does not inherited from _Layout page now. OR you can define separate CSS file for login page.

Comment: I got it, didn't need to create new `CSS`. The `CSS` is only referenced in the layout page and so the styles weren't being shown in the login page. I added to it the `CSS` reference and the styles are back. Thanks a lot @SoftSan

Comment: Glad that it helped you! You can mark it as Answer if it resolved your query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `section` of MVC views for this purpose. They are precisely used for this -

in `_layout.cshtml` include header section as this, so that the header is included as an optinal `section`

```
 @RenderSection("Header", False)
 @RenderSection("MainContent")
```

then other pages you can have separate header such as this (`some.cshtml`) -

```
@section Header {
    <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <a href="../Home/Index"><img src="../../Images/_logo.png" alt="whatever" /></a>
                </div>
}

@section MainContent{
     other body content.
}
```

And for `login` just don't define the `section` and only provide the body -

```
 @section MainContent{
     other body content.
}
```

This gives you not only the option to show hide header but also a great option to customize your layout based on the contents and need of the content pages.

You can learn more from here  -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383145/RenderBody-RenderPage-and-RenderSection-methods-in

and in msdn you can find the Documentation

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase_methods(v=vs.111).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase_methods%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Comment: Odd that this isn't the accepted answer. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the current user is authenticated, and if not then hide the elements you wish to hide.

```
@if(HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    ... stuff to show if user is authenticated here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a JQuery on your login page (cshtml). Use $(document).ready() event and hide the div containing the logo image.

Answer (score 0):

use script

```
 $(window).load(function () {
     $("#actionlinkid").hide = true;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Agree with solution given by Softsen. But in case you are asking only for hiding logo for particular page, You can do it as below:

```
  @if(Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("index")==-1)
            {
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
            }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not working. It shows the logo in every page. I switched the `==` to a `!=` and that way it hides the logo in every page

Comment: I don't thinks this a good idea. It is highly dependent on the route url. And if the url changes you have to change all your codes where you have such a check.